# Como evitar uma comparação por força bruta?

Tags: java

Possuindo uma classe qualquer `ClassA` que possui um atributo `value` e que, dependendo do tipo de `value` eu precise executar uma operação de maneira diferente, como eu evitaria uma comparação bruta, como no exemplo a seguir:

```java
public class Leitor()
{

    public String lerTipoDoValor(ClassA a)
    {
         //quero verificar se é int ou Integer
         if(a.getValue() instanceOf Integer.class)
         {
             //comandos
             return "O VALOR E INTEIRO"
         }
         //quero verificar se é Double ou double
         else if(a.getValue() instanceOf Double.class )
         {
            //comandos
            return "O VALOR E DOUBLE"
         }
         else if(a.getValue() instanceOf String.class )
         {
            //comandos
            return "O VALOR E STRING"
         }
         else if(a.getValue() instanceOf Boolean.class )
         {
            //comandos
            return "O VALOR E BOOLEAN"
         }
         else if(a.getValue() instanceOf List.class )
         {
            //comandos
            return "O VALOR E LIST"
         }
         //...
    }
}
```

Eu quero considerar tanto tipo primitivo, quanto sua classe correspondente, como, por exemplor, `int` e `Integer`.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo em concreto ou o contexto onde esta' a utilizar? A arquitectura das classes podera' nao ser a melhor para essa situacao em causa. Essa comparacao nao parece ideal (como referido)

Comment: Não dá pra resolver simplesmente com `a.getValue().getClass().getName()`? Daí é só criar um map e associar o nome da classe a um retorno.

Comment: Bom, o objetivo do meu projeto  e transformar uma bean em um formulario HTML usando anotações.

Comment: Não pois ali aonde comentei //comandos seria comandos diferentes para cada comparação.

Comment: O que representa a ClasseA no seu projecto?

Comment: para criar o formulario em html , as principais classes são BeanInfo(que amazerna a bean, e valores em anotações),FieldInfo(Amazernar a field e valores em anotações), BeanConverter(Convert a bean em tags html ),FieldConverter(converte a field em tags html), Tag(representa uma tag html), Attribute(representa um atributo html),o problema é na FieldConverter, sua principal função e criar inputs html, e para cada tipo de Atributo é gerado um input diferente ex : para um bool ou Boolean e gerado 2 RadioButtons, para um Date e gerado m input do tipo datetime-local e etç..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu não teria problemas com os `IF`s para uma rotina específica do sistema com um escopo bem limitado. Seria a forma mais limpa e eficiente.

Mas, se a ideia é temperar seu sistema com um pouco da mágica que os frameworks em geral tanto usam, eu adotaria uma abordagem diferente. Na verdade não é tanto diferente, pois no final das contas é baseada num mapa, como algumas respostas já o fizeram.

Todavia, a diferença fundamental está no tratamento do valor genérico que você quer colocar e tirar de um campo HTML. Não basta recuperar e saber o tipo de dado, é preciso atuar em cima dele. Se apenas colocarmos o tipo num mapa e recuperarmos, ainda acabaremos com vários `IF`s.

Uma situação pior ainda é quando os vários desenvolvedores começarem a adicionar tipos diferentes e personalizados aos beans. **Será que cada vez que uma nova necessidade surgir você vai precisar mexer nesse código? Não queira essa dor de cabeça!**

Uma abordagem seria usar o conceito de *conversores* (*converters*), a exemplo do JSF, JPA e outras APIs que já possuem esse tipo de recurso.

Estamos reinventando a roda? Sim! Mas vale a pena, nem que seja para aprendizado!

## Definindo um *Converter*

Vamos definir um conversor que é capaz de colocar e recuperar valores de campos HTML. Tudo o que precisamos é converter um valor de um tipo qualuqer para String e de String para o tipo novamente, ou seja, fazer a ida e a volta para um campo HTML.

```java
public interface Converter<T> {
    String toString(Object value);
    T fromString(String str);
}
```

## Implementando *Converters* básicos

### `String`

```java
public class StringConverter implements Converter<String> {

    @Override
    public String toString(Object value) {
        return value.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String fromString(String str) {
        return str;
    }

}
```

### `Integer`

```java
public class IntegerConverter implements Converter<Integer> {

    @Override
    public String toString(Object value) {
        return value.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Integer fromString(String str) {
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }

}
```

### `java.util.Date`

```java
public class DateConverter implements Converter<Date> {

    @Override
    public String toString(Object value) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Date fromString(String str) {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(str);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data inválida: '" + str + "'!");
        }
    }

}
```

## Gerenciando os *Converters*

Agora que temos alguns converters, vamos criar uma classe para gerenciar tudo isso.

```java
public class ConverterManager {

    private static Map<Class<?>, Converter<?>> converterMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, Converter<?>>();

    static {
        //default converters
        converterMap.put(String.class, new StringConverter());
        converterMap.put(Integer.class, new IntegerConverter());
        converterMap.put(Date.class, new DateConverter());
    }

    /**
     * Recupera um conversor de um tipo específico
     * @param classe Tipo do conversor
     * @return Instância do conversor
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> Converter<T> getConverter(Class<T> classe) {
        return (Converter<T>) converterMap.get(classe);
    }

    /**
     * Permite o registro de um novo conversor
     * @param classe Tipo do conversor
     * @param converter Instância do conversor
     */
    public static <T> void registerNewConverter(Class<T> classe, Converter<T> converter) {
        converterMap.put(classe, converter);
    }

}
```

A classe `ConverterManager` inicializa alguns conversores padrão e permite que o desenvolvedor registre novos conversores para os tipos que desejar.

## Exemplo de uso

Um exemplo simples de como fica um código de ida e volta:

```java
//um valor qualquer
Object val1 = 1;

//recupera o converter
Converter<?> converter = ConverterManager.getConverter(val1.getClass());

//converter para String
String str1 = converter.toString(val1);

//converte novamente para inteiro
Integer int1 = (Integer) converter.fromString(str1);
```

A diferença desse exemplo básico, é que no seu caso você vai precisar usar reflexão para executar os métodos *getter* e *setter* ou então acessar diretamente o *Field* em questão.

Creio que usar os atributos ao invés dos métodos é melhor, pois o código fica mais eficiente e limpo. Entretanto, isso pode causar problemas se houver alguma lógica nos métodos que seja importante.

Comment: cara, vlw genial resolução de problema, eu estava querendo saber justamente como estes frameworks tratavam o mesmo problema, a um tempo atrás, para fim didático, tentei fazer uma espécie de JPA para C#, porém acabei sendo ofuscado pelo mesmo problema

Comment: @user5020 Bom ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar um `Map`, usando como `Class<?>` como chave. Por exemplo:

```
public class Leitor
{
  private Map<Class<?>,String> tipoValor = new HashMap<Class<?>,String>();
  {
    tipoValor.put(Double.class, "O VALOR E DOUBLE");
    tipoValor.put(double.class, "O VALOR E DOUBLE");
    //...
    tipoValor.put(List.class, "O VALOR E LIST");
  }

  public String lerTipoDoValor(ClassA  a) {
    String res = tipoValor.get(a.getValue().getClass());
    if (res != null) {
      return res;
    }
    else {
      return "DESCONHECIDO";
    }
  }
}
```

Se você quiser algo mais complicado, em vez de usar `String` você pode colocar uma interface, como `Runnable`, e colocar uma lógica específica para cada tipo, por exemplo:

```
Map<Class<?>,Runnable> tipoValor = new HashMap<Class<?>,Runnable>();
tipoValor.put(Double.class, new Runnable(){
  public void run() {
    //Faz alguma coisa se for double
  }
});
tipoValor.put(Integer.class, new Runnable(){
  public void run() {
    //Faz alguma coisa se for int
  }
});
```

e depois:

```
Runnable r = tipoValor.get(a.getValue().getClass());
if (r != null) { 
    r.run();
}
```

Se você precisar receber parâmetros ou retornar um valor, pode criar sua própria interface.

Comment: cara muito boa  do Runnable, sabe quando você fica se queixando, porque não teve essa idéia antes , vlw pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia criar uma `HashMap` contendo os tipos e sua respectiva descrição. Então, se entendi direito o seu intuito, bastaria pesquisar a `HashMap` e capturar sua descrição correspondente. Ficaria assim:

```
HashMap<Object, String> mapa = new HashMap<Object, String>();
```

A grosso modo:

```
mapa.put(Integer.class, "Inteiro");
mapa.put(String.class, "String");
mapa.put(Decimal.class, "Decimal");
//e assim por diante
```

E como ficaria seu método:

```
public String lerTipoDoValor(ClassA a)
{
    System.out.println("O VALOR E " + mapa.get(a.class));
}
```

Acho que desta forma o código fica mais legível e organizado.

**UPDATE**

Após rever seus comentários, identifiquei que o seu intuito real é executar um código específico de acordo com o tipo de obejto, e não apenas retornar o seu tipo.
Sendo assim, segue minha opinião:

Criar uma interface:

```
public interface ITipo
{
    void ExecutaMetodo();
}
```

Implementar as classes, relacionadas aos tipos:

```
public class BehaviorInteger implements ITipo
{
    @Override
    public void ExecutarMetodo()
    {
        System.out.println("Este tipo é inteiro");
    }
}

public class BehaviorString implements ITipo
{
    @Override
    public void ExecutarMetodo()
    {
        System.out.println("Este tipo é String");
    }
}
```

Agora sim vem a questão do HashMap:

```
HashMap<Object, ITipo> mapa = new HashMap<Object, ITipo>();
```

Populando o HashMap:

```
mapa.put(Integer.class, new BehaviorInteger());
mapa.put(String.class, new BehavioString());
//e assim por diante
```

E como ficaria seu método:

```
public String lerTipoDoValor(ClassA a)
{
    mapa.get(a.class).ExecutarMetodo();
}
```

O código pode conter alguns erros de sintaxe, visto que não possuo nenhuma IDE Java no momento além desta não ser minha linguagem principal de trabalho.

Creio que esta é a melhor forma de implementação devido a organização do código e facilidade para manutenção.

Ah. Não esqueça de verificar que o tipo está contido no HashMap antes de executar o método.

Comment: em HashMap é possível acrescentar uma função, ou método no valor?

Comment: @user5020, editei minha resposta com a solução para sua pergunta.

Comment: `a.class` não compila. Se a chave do seu `Map` é uma classe, você não deveria usar `Object`. Não existe uma classe chamada `Decimal`. Tentei editar a sua resposta duas vezes, mas as edições foram rejeitadas.

Comment: Desculpe @Victor, mas iniciei agora no SO e ainda estou me acostumando. Vi que você editou corretamente, mas não encontrei a opção para aceitar as alterações. Por isto que informei na minha resposta que Java não é minha linguagem principal de trabalho e que não possuo nenhuma IDE Java instalada no momento. Sendo assim, agradeço a sua contribuição e seu tempo despendido.

Answer (score 0):

Julgo que o modo mais correto é a classe `A` implementar uma `interface`.

Cada classe implementará a `interface` de acordo com o tipo de dados que contém.

O código que usa essas classes não precisará de saber nada à cerca da classe, bastar-lhe-á chamar o método da `interface` e a classe executará os comandos apropriados.

Comment: Até pensei nisto, porém, teria que criar uma factory que iria usar a mesma comparação bruta para fabricar o objeto

Comment: Como não conheço o contexto em que você usa essas classes e onde as tem de as instanciar, não consigo acrescentar mais nada à minha resposta. De qualquer forma julgo que a `factory`será uma melhor solução.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a melhor opção seja usar Overloading na sua classe. Assim você implementa o mesmo método diversas vezes, cada um aceitando um tipo de parâmetro. Por exemplo:

```
public class Leitor()
{
    public String lerTipoDoValor(ClassA a)
    {
         return this.interpretaA(a.getValue());
    }

    public String interpretaA(Integer value)
    {
        return "O VALOR E INTEIRO";
    }

    public String interpretaA(Double value)
    {
        return "O VALOR E DOUBLE";
    }

    public String interpretaA(String value)
    {
        return "O VALOR E STRING";
    }

    public String interpretaA(Boolean value)
    {
        return "O VALOR E BOOLEAN";
    }

    public String interpretaA(List value)
    {
        return "O VALOR E LIST";
    }
}
```

Comment: O parametro passado por argumento seria sempre do tipo ClassA, fazendo com que seus overloads nunca iriam ser invocados.

Comment: @JoaoRaposo `a` é uma instância de `ClasseA` (por isso o método `lerTipoDoValor`), entretanto o valor recebido por `a.getValue()` pode ser uma instância de qualquer classe.

Comment: Tem toda a razao, sem o contexto do problema diria que e' uma solucao para evitar todos os if's encadeados. +1

Comment: A sobrecarga de funções na sua resposta é resolvida em tempo de compilação. Nesse momento, o tipo de `a.getValue()` é (provavelmente) `Object`, e na prática só uma função seria chamada sempre. É preciso checar o tipo do objeto em tempo de execução.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser agora eu fiquei na dúvida, já que não sou um programador Java. Outra possível solução seria fazer um map de/para associando strings das possíveis classes com um callback.

Comment: Pois é, foi o que eu propus na minha resposta :)

Comment: @C.E.Gesser Foi uma resposta digna de programador Java :)

Comment: Sendo programador de .net a resposta faz todo o sentido. Nao posso comentar para java. @rodrigorigotti falta so' um "return" no primeiro metodo.

Comment: Na realidade eu programo muito pouco ultimamente. 99% do meu trabalho é com C++ hoje em dia.

Comment: em todos os casos chamaria sempre o interpretarA(Object obj), mas valeu